# kubectl cannot connect to private gke-cluster with Enable control plane global access

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

kubectl cannot connect to private gke-cluster with Enable control plane global access. getting the error Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp IP_ADDRESS:443: i/o timeout.

checked the cluster configurations and network settings .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Kubectl is unable to communicate with the cluster control plane.
Could you kindly check to see whether the **Control plane authorised networks** settings is enabled or disabled?

If its enabled you must edit the settings of your cluster and add your IPaddress/32  to control plane authorised networks. see[cluster settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuCaK.png)

As Control plane authorised networks is enabled, it will allow only configured source ip ranges

Comment: Thank you .It helped me to connect .now am able to connect to cluster :).